# Python robobrowser get_form isn't getting the whole form

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, robobrowser

I am using robobrowser to automate a search on a website. I need to fill in two form inputs but the robobrowser.get_form is only picking up the first input. Any ideas on how to get the full form and assign a value to the second input?

HTML:

```
<form name="form1" method=post action="/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_r2trastrep2">
<h5 align= "center"><font face_"verdana,arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="4">Enter The Report Date(MM/YYYY): 
<input type="text" Name="p_r2reportdate" size="6" maxlength="7">
</font></p>
<h5 align= "center"><font face_"verdana,arial, helvetica, sans-serif" size="4">Enter The Transporter ID: 
<input type="text" name="p_r2trans_id" size="6" maxlength="7">
</font></p>
<input type="submit" >
</font></p>
  </form>
```

Python script:

```
import re 
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser 
sonris = 'http://sonlite.dnr.state.la.us/sundown/cart_prod/CART_CON_r2trastrep1'
former1 = "p_r2reportdate"
former2 = "p_r2trans_id"
date = '01/2016'
code = '7250' #capline
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True,parser='html.parser') 
browser.open(sonris)
form = browser.get_form(action="/sundown/cart_prod/cart_con_r2trastrep2")
print(form) #<RoboForm p_r2reportdate=>
form[former1].value = date
form[former2].value = code
browser.submit_form(form)
print(str(browser.parsed))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that I can see if that the second parameter has the name attribute in lower case "name" as opposed to "Name" for the earlier. So I suggest if you can fix the source do it else get the input field from the form using another attribute and then set its value.